# Is there a list available of plugins compatible with QGIS 3.0 Girona?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

On February 23rd, QGIS 3.0 Girona was officially released.
I read in the documentation that the release contains breaking changes that will affect some or all of the existing QGIS plugins.

I've been searching for a list that tells whether

- a plugin is known as being compatible with 3.0
- a plugin is known as *not* being compatible with 3.0 and planned to be made compatible by its developer
- a plugin is known as *not* being compatible with 3.0 and abandoned by its developer
- a plugin has an unknown status

Compatibility doesn't seem to be shown on https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/. 
Does anyone know of (an initiative to make) such a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of all plugins that support >= 3.0 use https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=3.0

This is the same listing that the built-in QGIS Plugin Manager uses to determine the list of plugins that can be installed.